# android GCM doesn't receive messages on huawei but it is fine on galaxy s2

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm developing an android application for a company, the application works fine on galaxy s2 but when I tried it on huawei honor2 and huawei tab it doesn't receive gcm messages, even the broadcast receiver doesn't work at all, any help appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: did you check the availability of Google Paly services?

Comment: did you solved this issue? i am fetching this when app is removed from task list.